# How to put array data into table?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I need some help with php code.
I want to put data that I get with this query into simple php/html table.

Can you guys help me with this?

```
<?php

$konekcija=mysqli_connect("111.111.111.111","test","test123","publishers_instagram_accounts");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    die ("Error:".mysqli_connect_error());

$select = "select * from publishers_instagram_accounts where followed_id <= (select followed_id from publishers_instagram_accounts where username='zika')*1.2 and followed_id >= (select followed_id from publishers_instagram_accounts where username='zika')*0.8";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($konekcija, $select);

if (mysqli_error($konekcija))
    die ("Error:" . mysqli_error($konekcija));

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $trazi1, $trazi2);

if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
    die ("Error:" . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}
else
{
    $rezultat = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    while ($red = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        var_dump($red);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($red = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 echo "
 <table>
  <thead>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Password</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>$red['username']</td>
    <td>$red['password']</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
 ";
}
```

Something like this.. Hope it helps you.

Comment: You can't reference array keys inside double-quotes like that.  You need to either use `$red[username]` or `{$red['username']}`

Comment: I only noticed because I've made that same mistake a thousand times

Answer (score 0):

Hello @filipche you can try by replacing your 'while' loop with following code:

```
echo "<table><thead><tr><th>Field 1</th><th>Field 2</th><th>Field 3</th></tr></thead>";
while ($red = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<tbody><tr>";
   echo "<td>".$red["field1"]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$red["field2"]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$red["field3"]."</td>";
   echo "</tr><tbody>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: This won't 'scale'. Using mysqli_fetch_fields and iterating would be far better.

Comment: Yes it is true, but that was not the problem definition :)

Comment: In OP stands `I want to put data that I get with this query into simple php/html table.` and he uses `select *` so I think it is the thing he wants.

Comment: It is still **simple php/html table** but not scalable.

Answer (score -1):

```
$qstring = "Your query goes here";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);
if($result)
{
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
          echo "<table>";
          echo "<td>".$row[column name]."</td>";echo "</table>";
     }
```